Are you following the official RE Twitter account?
If you're a Twitter fan and spend time retweeting questions, you may want to consider following @StackReverseEng.
https://twitter.com/StackReverseEng/
StackReverseEng is the official Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange Twitter account created by the Stack Exchange team. It's configured to automatically tweet certain questions. It tweets about two posts daily.
This could help expose RE.SE to more of your followers and encourage us all to retweet more questions.

The event is now over.
Our Twitter account went from having 13 followers to 23 followers during the event! 
@StackReverseEng is the second most followed account for all beta sites <1 year old.
